# How did my import result in the State for a different country to the one intended

Tags: database, data-import

How could a CiviCRM database have 2 Marylands with 2 different `state_province_code`s but both be identified with the same `country_code`?

1019 = Maryland
3497 = Maryland
1228 = United States

I only was alerted to this when my newly inherited client created a Smart Group to display all records with `postal_code` between 20601 and 21930.

Is my CiviCRM instance corrupt or has a bad import caused this? Can I manually adjust the offending records without cascading problems? How would you suggest a fix for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you're not using the latest version of CiviCRM (4.7.30 at the time of writing).  It sounds like you're experiencing the bug that was described and fixed at [CRM-19888](https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-19888).  It's also related to this [much older bug](https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-7597).

Please upgrade to 4.7.30 and try again?

Answer (score 2):

I may not have quite understood you but if you have access to your database you can look in civicrm_state_province where you will see there is a Maryland MY in Liberia (1122) as well as a Maryland MD in the USA (1228)

[image]

When importing contacts with State/Province you may be better off if you either import the abbreviation (though even that might not be unique) or also import Country.

Comment: I can see in the database: 1019 - Maryland - 1228. Yet, during someone's import the database decided on its own to assign over 600 records this: 3497 - Maryland - 1228
Thanks for sharing how this might have occurred.

Comment: nw. i edited the Title/Question to try and better reflect the issue